# How to pass image view from view controller to tab bar view controller without segue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a registration form for users in the view controller where the user sets a profile image and there is a tab bar controller with the "my profile" tab where this image should appear after registration. How can I transfer the image from the registration form to the tab controller "my profile"? From addPhotoImage (view controller) to userPhotoImage (tab view controller).

```
import UIKit

class SigninViewController: UIViewController {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBOutlet var countPlaceInCar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var nameOfCar: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var AddPhotoButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var registerButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var registrationSegmented: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet var addPhotoImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var phoneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        makeRounded()    
    }

    //func that rounded image for user
    func makeRounded() {
        addPhotoImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        addPhotoImage.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        addPhotoImage.layer.cornerRadius = addPhotoImage.frame.height/2 //This will change with corners of image and height/2 will make this circle shape
        addPhotoImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }

    @IBAction func addPhotoFromLibraryOrCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

extension SigninViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            addPhotoImage.image = image


        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

import UIKit

class FourthViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var messageForUser: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var routeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var userPhotoImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. You want to transfer the `UIImage`, not the `UIImageView`.
`UIImage` is a data representation of an image. 
`UIImage` just displays the image.

You could use a singleton like this:

```
class UserManager {
    static let shared = UserManager()

    var image: UIImage?
}
```

Then you can access it from everywhere like this

```
UserManager.shared.image
```

Be aware that with this approach, the image will be in memory for the time the app is in memory. So use this only if you need the picture all the time.

Comment: if i don't need the picture all the time?

Comment: You could set the `image` property of the singleton to `nil` after displaying it in your _tab view controller_. This way you'd prevent memory leakage.

Comment: Another way would be to retrieve a reference of the _tab view controller_ inside the _registration controller_. But for that we must know how both of them are related to another. E.g. is one of them being presented on top of the other?

Comment: but how to connect UserManager.shared.image with IBOutlet var addPhotoImage: UIImageView! in registration form(view controller) and  IBOutlet var userPhotoImage: UIImageView! (tab bar view controller) ?

Comment: You don't have to connect them. You can save the image in the registration controller to the `UserManager` and retrieve it in the other controller. Use the lifecycle methods, e.g. `viewWillAppear(_:)` to set the image like this: `userPhotoImage.image = UserManager.shared.image`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the image in memory then fl034's solution works well. If you wish to store the image in a persistent store so that it's available regardless of restarts etc then the below solution will store the image in the Document Directory and can be accessed later:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        addPhotoImage.image = image

        // Choose where to save the image, use a unique identifier to make it
        // user specific

        let uniqueIdentifier = someUniqueUserIdentifier            

        let fileName = getDocumentDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(uniqueIdentifier)_profileImage")

        // Write the image to the Document Directory

        do {

            try image.write(to: fileName)

        } catch let error as NSError {

            // Handle any errors

            print("ERROR:", error)
            return
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then when you want to load the image from the Document Directory and assign it to an UIImageView for presentation:

```
func loadProfileImageFromDirectory(uniqueIdentifier: String) {

    // Dynamically select appropriate filepath

    let fileName = getDocumentDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(uniqueIdentifier)_profileImage")

    guard let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: fileName) else { return }

    let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data)

    // Set image view

    someImageView.image = loadedImage
}
```